# How to prevent VSCode from asking me to save other unsaved files when saving one file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

After I saved a file, VSCode would jump to other files I've edited and asked me to save them as well. I don't want that behaviour as it moves me out of context from the current file I'm editing.

Anyone knows how to stop VSCode from doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is too late, but it might help other people.

Logically, VS code is correct, but another option can help you not get the popup asking to save the unsaved files. Look for the below option in VS code shortcut settings.

File.Save All Files (workbench.action.files.saveFiles)

[image]

This will only save previously saved files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. I removed the Key Binding to `File: Save All Files` as shown above and bound the keyboard shortcut `⌘ S` (for mac) to `File: Save` only

Comment: Additionally, if you are configuring shortcuts, the `saveAll` command will attempt to save unsaved files, but the `workbench.action.files.saveFiles` command (*specifically*) will only save existing files.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I'm aware of is to kill the vscode process, unfortunately I don't know how to identify the exact window I want to kill, so that usually means killing all vscode processes. They all reload when you open vscode the next time.